# How to make sure parked domains are not used in urls?

Tags: php, .htaccess, multiple-domains

I have a website, let's say 123.com. I have a parked domain on this, abc.com
I am redirecting abc.com to 123.com/hello .
This works fine. My goal is that once visitors browse my website, only see 123.com as the main url.

In Google search results I notice the following:
123.com/blog/some-article.html and also abc.com/blog/some-article.com
So I checked my site: 
When I browse it, only the main url (abc.com) is shown.. but i can change the url manually to 123.com, anywhere on the site, it works as well.

My question: How can I prevent this from happening?
do I have to add some additional rewrite / redirects to a .htaccess ?

Comment: Pretty simple mate, don't use a parked domain, instead, use an addon domain, and then use a proper redirect.

Comment: Thanks, but from what I understand is that an addon domain is used for a website with its own unique content. This is not the case here. I only have 1 website with unique content.

Comment: Regardless, the functionality you're experiencing is because the parked domain is built in such a way that all data associated with it is accessed through the primary domain's content. If you create a subdomain and use a 301 permanent redirect then it'll work fine. Alternatively, you can use an `.htaccess` file to ensure all requests for `abc.com/whatever` are sent to `123.com/whatever`

Comment: Ok, clear :) Thanks Ohgodwhy!